# How to create indicator variable in R considitonal of 2 other variables being the same?

Tags: r, dataframe, boolean

first at all I am very new to R, so sorry if it is a silly question (but I did browse before..)

I have a df with two integers varA and varB (where varB could be NA) and I need to create a third variable that is 1 if varA and varB are equal or 0 if not or if varB is NA.

I did already tried (unsuccessfully) these approaches:

```
mydf$varC <- 0
mydf$varC[(!is.na(mydf$varB)) && (mydf$varA == mydf$varB)] <- 1

mydf$varC <- ifelse(mydf$varA == mydf$varC, 1, 0)
```

Comment: What if VarA is NA?

Comment: Thank you. Actually the two approaches work (the first one with just one `&`), I just misspelled the varB  name (but R didn't warned me!). An other approach is to use mutate: `mutate(my_tbldf, varC = (varA == varB))` (that has the advantage of telling you if `varA` or `varB` do not exists!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
df = data.frame(varA = c(1,1,0,0),
                varB = c(1,0,0,NA))

df$flag = ifelse(df$varA == df$varB & !is.na(df$varB), 1, 0)

#   varA varB flag
# 1    1    1    1
# 2    1    0    0
# 3    0    0    1
# 4    0   NA    0
```

The new column (`flag`) will be `1` only if the values are the same **and** when `varB` is not `NA`. In any other case (i.e. values are not the same **or** `varB` is `NA`) it will be `0`.